# Question is tagged both [c] and [c++], but has no reason to be

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, specific-question

A user posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46979509/7076153). I think it's a clear, good question, but the OP tagged it with both the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tags. I see no reason to tag two languages in this question, but when I objected, the OP replied:

> Abso[expletivedeleted]lutely not. A C specific answer is as acceptable as a C++
>   specific answer. I happen to use a C++ specific answer but atof is
>   usable. There's no reason to make this two questions when one would do

*(Expletive deleted above was present in the comment.)*

For context, here are *all* of the comments circling that discussion:
<sub>(they've been purged from the question on the main site, so that discussion can occur here instead)</sub>

> [image]

This is wrong for me. If we think like that, then why not add *all* programming languages to this question? C# looks close enough for me.

So, what do you think about this? For me, this question is too broad because the answers need to be C and C++ compliant for no reason. Am I wrong?

Note: I want to stop [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20c%2B%2B?sort=votes&mode=all) problem. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19830820/7076153) answer explains my point very well. A lot of questions are too broad because we need to give two different solutions in order to have a complete answer. A potential viewer who only seeks a C++ solution will be confused, and the same for someone seeking a C solution. This wastes everyone's time.

Comment: The solution is equally valid in both language. The target language is C++ however I knew the solution would be in C. If I was wrong I would change the tags. Since the solution is valid for both there's no reason to remove the tags and people may offer a more preferred C++ solution if they wish.

Comment: I disagree this is a good, clear question; the question is simply too broad. That it is tagged with multiple languages only made it more so. I see it is already closed as such, good.

Comment: *"Since the solution is valid for both"* This is the fatal flaw. There is no way that the person asking the question can know that, because it requires you to first know the answer for both C and C++, and then verify that they are the same. That's not how tags are supposed to work. You tag with the language you want the solution to be in, which is almost certainly the language you are programming in.

Comment: @Cody /OT Nice halloween gag ;-)

Comment: @CodyS.Pumpkins: Since it has solutions that are valid in C and valid in C++ should it only have one language tag or not?

Comment: @Stargateur  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358586/if-questions-should-not-be-tagged-as-c-and-c-why-are-they-being-closed-because

Comment: Why duplicate the questions and discussion points @acidzombie24? Your opposition would be much better served as an answer on this question.

Comment: @CodyS.Pumpkins: Maybe you'd like to comment https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358586/if-questions-should-not-be-tagged-as-c-and-c-why-are-they-being-closed-because

Comment: @acidzombie24 Duplicates are a completely separate issue from tagging. There, the people who vote to close as duplicates *are* expected to be experts in the relevant technologies, and thus can make the determination whether the answer is identical for both C and C++.

Comment: @GhostlyMartijn: Why is it not clear? The subject line is 100% clear backed up with a question that EXPLICITLY states the input, output and the format it's in. I challenge you to explain your words

Comment: @CodyS.Pumpkins probably my last question to you. In your opinion why was the question put on hold for being too broad? IMO there's nothing broad about it and a comment+moderator flag would address the tagging issue

Comment: I looked at re-opening it when I first saw this Meta question, because I think there's definitely a valid question there, but I still think it's too broad as currently framed. Why? Simply because you haven't chosen/specified a language yet. @acidzombie24

Comment: @CodyS.Pumpkins: Thank you. I rolled it back to the original which has both C and C++. Just because I will accept both and people closed the C version to the C++ answer. I'd still like someone to answer in a C specific way if they so choose. If it's a problem people can edit my question or flag a mod which is how I think it should be handled in the first place

Comment: @acidzombie24 I honestly don't understand what you are trying to say. Flagging a moderator wouldn't do any good. I *am* a moderator, and there's nothing for me to do there, other than to impose my own views on the question by editing it. If you want a C answer, then just tag the question [c].

Comment: @acidzombie24 The answer for each language is not the same. The underlying concept is similar. The application of it is significantly different between the languages. See my answer for further discussion.

Comment: @jpmc26 If those answers are not the same, then why was the c-tagged question closed as duplicate and quickly downvoted? I hope I am not going to get some ban for saying it for the second time. I wasn§t even able to read the reaction.

Comment: @VladimirF Some people downvote duplication for no reason plus both questions are still unclear. I upvote the duplicate for myself because the question don't deserve so much downvote. I can't do more.

Comment: Oh look! This again! I think the only rational solution to this problem is to burninate both tags, then run all badgeholders out of town on a rail.

Comment: @VladimirF I don't know. I don't think it should have been.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I think it's a clear, good question,

I think it's not.  Even leaving the tagging issue aside for the moment, it's unclear to me just what is being asked.  Does the OP want to convert a decimal string to a IEEE-754 bit pattern (*i.e.* an object of type `double` in most C and C++ implementations you'll meet today), or to a hexadecimal or binary digit string?  Or maybe even to a bit pattern in a 64-bit integer object?  Is he looking for an algorithm for performing such a conversion manually, or for code involving the library functions that one would use in a real-world program?

> but the OP tagged it with both the c and c++ tags.

... which doesn't help at all without some explanation.  Tags help categorize questions for future reference, but they also serve to help clarify what kind of answer is sought.  The OP's comments that he does not care which of the two distinct languages the answer uses make the question unequivocally too broad.  Good SO questions do not intentionally solicit a diversity of fundamentally different answers.

Now, there are reasons why a given question might warrant both [c] and [c++] tags.  @jpmc26 presents two such reasons in his answer:

- the question requests a solution usable in both languages
- the question is about differences between the two languages

Another possibility might be

- the question requires an implementation in one language that can be called from the other

Any of these alternatives requires explanation in the question to clarify the OP's intent.

Of course, the particular case of [c] and [c++] is a somewhat notorious one here, owing in part to a distressingly widespread misunderstanding about the nature of the relationship between these languages.  It is not clear whether the OP suffered from this misunderstanding, but from their comments it certainly seems that they did not recognize or appreciate how utterly routine it is here to emphasize the distinction and to insist that OPs choose one language in cases that do not inherently involve both.

The OP's initial response, now removed, was furthermore inappropriate, warranting a flag for abusive language.  But having said that, engaging in a debate over the matter was not a useful exercise.  The baseline solution to such a tagging problem is to flag or vote to close, and in this particular case, VTC as "too broad" seems just right.  Indeed, the question has now been closed for that reason.  It was a courtesy to point out the issue in hope, I suppose, of prompting the OP to improve the question.  To the extent that you meant it any other way, you helped make the mess.  By allowing yourself to be drawn into a debate over what are essentially the facts of our culture and practice, you helped make the mess bigger.  After your initial comment was received so poorly, it would have been better to just walk away.

Comment: I agree about the quality of the question, I think that answers help me to understand the question and so confuse me about this fact. The question was indeed not clear. I just create a meta question to discute about tags of the question with other peoples. Cause the user had a big reputation, I was thinking that maybe I was wrong. Now, I fell that I start a war without wanting to, I'm sorry about that. I will follow your advice next time.

Answer (score 30):

First of all, I want to point out that your, "Why not add Python and Ruby?" argument doesn't work here. Mixing C and C++ code is [not unheard of](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp). It's even possible to [go the other way around](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2744181/1394393) and call C++ code from C. C++, being developed as a modification of C, also supports significantly similar syntax. The association of the two languages is well recognized: [Compatibility of C and C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B). They also notably compile to compatible binary formats. By comparison, Python and Ruby are *fundamentally* different languages targeting incompatible runtimes, and writing code compatible with both is unheard of outside of [polyglot code challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot). Asking a question about two languages with such strong historical and practical ties is not the same as asking a question about several completely disparate, unrelated languages.

But that doesn't mean your conclusion is wrong.

In the most general case, C++ and C are separate languages with separate standards and compilers. There is no guarantee that these languages will not diverge further, and more importantly, the standard idioms of C++ are not going to be the same idioms as C since C++ added significant features and took some syntax away. **While mixing them is possible, it requires diligence and care.**

Because of this, it's important to make the question and the tags clearly reflect the desired end result:

- If the asker is specifically looking for a solution compatible with both languages, then the question should note this restriction explicitly and use both tags. This may be unusual, but it is not outside the realm of feasibility. (An answer saying that this is impractical for the specific task would be completely reasonable as a response, as long as it explains why.)
- If the user is explicitly asking a question about specific differences between the languages, then it clearly should be tagged with both. Answerers will require knowledge about both languages to be able to answer.
- If the asker is working in C++ but is fine with solutions that are more idiomatic in C, then they should note this in the question but **only tag as C++**. The question is asking for solutions for a C++ compiler, not a C one. The differences may matter, so answerers need to know what platform they're targeting.
- If the asker is looking for solutions in both languages but is fine with the solutions being different, then the question is Too Broad and should be split into two questions, one for each language. The advantage of doing so is that future users looking for C solutions can find one without dealing with the clutter of C++ solutions, and vice versa. If a standard, idiomatic solution that works for both exists, it can be posted in both questions (possibly with a link making the relationship clear).

It's all about making your question clear so that it gets you the desired result and then using the tags to reach the users who will have the knowledge necessary to answer. Even though many C experts are also experts in C++ and vice versa, it's still important for potential answerers to know *what kind of question* they're answering when they see it.

For the specific question at hand, I'd actually have closed as Unclear. It doesn't make the language(s) they're actually targeting or the reason for using both tags clear. This can make a large difference in terms of what solutions are viable. However, given that the answer they accepted includes disparate solutions in both languages, Too Broad seems applicable as well.

Comment: Objective-C is still a strict superset of C. Why not add an Objective-C tag? In practice, no one does this. For some reason, there is a widespread misperception that C and C++ are the same language. Otherwise (i.e., beyond the first paragraph), yes, I agree with this answer.

Comment: @CodyS.Pumpkins I agree they're not the same language. (I call this out in the second paragraph.) But is it untrue that C and C++ have a longstanding, close relationship that does not exist with Objective-C? Maybe it's not due simply to the fact C++ was originally a strict superset. Any ideas what else it could be? Or does Objective-C also have a longstanding close relationship with C?

Comment: Yes, it's totally untrue. The relationship between C and Objective-C is *much* closer, in that Objective-C is just a set of object extensions to C and is, by design, a strict superset of C. That's not the case with C++, and hasn't been for a long time. Sure, Bjarne wrote C++ as a modification of C, and the first version of C++ was essentially "C With Classes", but it hasn't been that language for a *very* long time. I suspect the real reason why Objective-C is kept distinct is the platform divide. Being common on NeXT and recently Mac, it isn't popular on Unix or Windows where C and C++ reign.

Comment: C++98, the first true standard of C++ has never been a strict super-set of C89. Some funny [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887700/can-code-that-is-valid-in-both-c-and-c-produce-different-behavior-when-compile). Whatever, the important point is that C++ is mostly a object oriented language and C is mostly a imperative language. I think even for python 2 and python 3 I will prefer two questions. I agree with the rest of your answer.

Comment: @CodyS.Pumpkins and Stargateur: I've reworked that section significantly. The Python comparison suggested a much closer relationship than I intended to. Instead, I've outsourced some discussion about similarities and usage of the two together. Better?

Comment: @jpmc26 Sorry, I don't agree whatever the form you will use, your first paragraph is only true when we were in 1980-90. C has "strong historical" with B and go has "strong historical" with C. About binary formats asm and C++ both compile to binary formats so they are close enough ? The real thing is that C and C++ in **practice and theory** are not compatible, C is not anymore close to C++, they just share some syntax and keyword. I don't know much about objective-C but it look like people say that is a strict super-set of C. So your first paragraphe would make sense for objective-C.

Comment: "Mixing C and C++ code is not unheard of." - Erm, no, you cannot mix C and C++ **source-code**! All you can do is use the C ABI from C++. It still is C++ code. It's the same as calling C functions from e.g. Python or Fortran. Do you consider them compatible, too? Since C99/C++98, both languages have diverged quite a lot and with C++11 the drift has accelerated a lot. Identical syntax/grammar does not imply identical semantics. Try `static const int i = 10; static a[i];` for example.

Comment: @Olaf isocpp.org's choice of words, not mine. =p Also see [HostileFork's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358604/1394393).

Comment: @jpmc26: They don't mix **source-code**. They just do the same as "mixing" C and Fortran. That does no way make them the same or even compatible. It is just the ABI which is compatible. It has nothing to do with the languages, **except** in C++ one can enforce the platforms C ABI with a syntax construct. The code in `extern "C"` is still C++ code!

Comment: Of course, one could write C-style C++ code, but as can be seen in the original question/answers, they already differ in the way how to type-pun. What is explicitly legal in C is UB in C++, although both constructs are syntactically identical. Of course one could use the common intersection of both languages, but that would be much smaller than expected and one always had to care if they changed in future revisions of one standard. But if you only know a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.

Answer (score 6):

Tagging with C and C++ is appropriate when one is trying to write code that will compile under both standards.

Are these people lunatics?  Well, let me cite the [C++ core guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#S-cpl) from ISO:

> C rule summary:
>
> CPL.1: Prefer C++ to C
>
> CPL.2: If you must use C, use the common subset of C and C++, and compile the C code as C++
>
> CPL.3: If you must use C for interfaces, use C++ in the code using such interfaces

Using C++'s static analysis behaviors in a codebase that can still fall back on a C compiler is actually kind of cool, and can be super relevant if you're the kind of person who is deep in bootstrap issues (e.g. you're a compiler author). 
 That's *how you have to think*.

But I guess we would assume people at that level of sophistication would know how to contextualize their StackOverflow questions and explain their situation clearly, such that people aren't going to jump all over them.

I think this question's problem is exactly that...it doesn't contextualize enough.  If people explain what they're doing and why, then there are plenty of contexts where you can use both the C and C++ tags.  It's just that most people with legitimate questions in that arena probably can read the specs and figure out answers themselves, because they're probably writing compilers.

Homework questions tagged both C and C++ are a shame on whoever's teaching that class.

Comment: The funny part is the answers of this question explicit say that the behavior will differs for unions for type punning between c and c++, so this is a typical technical question where C++ is not a super set of C.

Comment: While I agree that a question tagged with both is not insane and that the OP did not make their intentions clear (see my answer), I actually think your conclusion about contextualizing is wrong here. The OP ended up accepting an answer that contains different code samples for each language. It doesn't appear that either one is compatible with both languages. So the OP seems to have actually been asking two questions in one.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not so terribly interested in this question vs. just dispelling the knee-jerk reaction that tagging both C and C++ is wrong.  It's often used wrong, and more often than not used wrong on Stack Overflow.  But as others rightly point out, hybridized codebases in which C evolves to C++ is why C++ wears the hairshirt of C syntax in the first place.  Just want to rewire that automatic reaction that some here have towards questions with both tags.

Comment: Then perhaps consider reworking the section that starts with, "I think this question's problem is exactly that...it doesn't contextualize enough," so that your answer doesn't make a specific claim about this question?

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not that invested to go through a multi-phase editing process, this is hopefully not going to be inscribed on my tombstone, you've said what you have to say and I feel comfortable with it as written.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

C++ is technically *NOT* a superset of C.  That said, for most practical purposes, almost all C answers would be one way of doing something in C++.  The converse is not true.  As an unrelated aside, try searching for jobs in 'C' programming language.... or programming info .... or anything else .... sometimes there's a distinct disadvantage in having a one-character name!

Answer (score -3):

There are cases where both a C++ and C tag are appropriate.  This question may not be one, but if we're talking about putting two language tags on one question, then that shouldn't be disallowed.

C++ programs can access C libraries.  It's common.  C++ provides *standard* wrappers around C-library facilities. C++ purists may not like it, but real C++ programs use C libraries even if C++ has a replacement for it.

It's totally reasonable for some questioner to just want to get the job done and not worry about whether the answer is correct with the C++ gods of style.  (And here I'm speaking as someone who loves C++ and strongly *prefers* C++ solutions to C++ problems.  But I definitely understand that POV.)

(I would expect similarly that a question involving some framework/library available on the JVM could be tagged, say, both Scala and Java, if the OP's intent was to get an answer that could be used in Scala.  Or F# and C#.)

Comment: The first paragraph is incorrect. The question isn't asking anything to do with standard libraries. None of the top-scoring answers even *use* standard library functions, except for unrelated tasks like printing the output for testing purposes. This is entirely a language semantics question. Beyond that, it is true that C code libraries are often used from C++, but that doesn't merit a [c] tag. If you're writing the code to target a C++ compiler, then you tag with [c++]. It has nothing to do with purism. Tagging is a very practical thing.

Comment: @CodyS.Pumpkins  You're right: first paragraph is wrong, and I'll remove it, and make other edits to match.  I agree that tagging is a practical thing, but I disagree that tagging a question with both C++ and C is wrong in cases involving libraries.

Comment: If you are *writing* the C library, then using a [c] tag is appropriate. If you're simply *consuming* an existing C library from a C++ application, then the [c] tag is *probably* not a good idea. Note that in my mind this is no different than when you're interoperating a C library with a Python application. You want Python experts to answer the question, not C experts, so you would tag with [python], *not* [c]. Another tricky but related case is "translation" questions. The *destination* language should be tagged, not the source language. The latter is just incidental context.

Comment: I think the basic problem with this answer that I have is that if calling C libraries from C++ is common, there's no reason to think a C++ developer wouldn't be aware of appropriate C libraries that answer the question. And on the contrary, a C developer that doesn't know C++ might suggest libraries that are *inappropriate* for C++, due to not having detailed knowledge of relevant differences.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you misunderstood me, I never say that there are no questions that could be tagged with C and C++ but I don't think this question is one of them. A no random example: [Can code that is valid in both C and C++ produce different behavior when compiled in each language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887700/can-code-that-is-valid-in-both-c-and-c-produce-different-behavior-when-compile)

Comment: We do tag questions interfacing C and Fortran with both tags all the time. The same with C++ and Fortran.  I can never get why that is a mortal sin with C and C++. You may need people.who are experienced in both languages at the same time.

Comment: @VladimirF It's not so much that tagging with both is a mortal sin as much as it is that 1) it's not clear what the user is looking for and what expertise is required to answer, and 2) if the user isn't looking specifically to interface between them, the best (most idiomatic, safest) solution might be *very* different between the languages. In the latter case, it's better just to have separate questions so that the answers can be maintained independently as the languages change over time. Maybe only one language will add new standard library functions that solve the problem more cleanly.

Comment: That was a reaction to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358560/question-is-tagged-both-c-and-c-but-has-no-reason-to-be/358597?noredirect=1#comment526863_358597